# Knockout flatpickr bindingHandler leaking memory

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, memory-leaks, flatpickr

I've written a custom bindingHandler for Knockout, for the [Flatpickr](https://github.com/chmln/flatpickr) widget. The problem is it's leaking memory when it's being destroyed. The heap is filled with detached DOM tree entries.

[Jsfiddle of my code](https://jsfiddle.net/RedShift1/2vujuwxa/3/)

[Screenshot of heap memory](https://endeavour.webmind.be/~glenn/flatpickr-memory-leak.png)

The obvious suspect is the "ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback" function call. I've added a console.log to the dispose callback and the console is printing it so the callback is definitely firing. What else can I do to prevent this memory leak?

The bindingHandler in question:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.flatpickr =
{
    init: function(element, valueAccessor)
    {
        const el = $(element);
        const picker = new Flatpickr(element,
            {
                inline: true,
                enableTime: true,
                time_24hr: true,
                minuteIncrement: 1
            }
        );

        el.data('pickrInstance', picker);

        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'change',
            function ()
            {
                valueAccessor()(moment(picker.selectedDates[0]));
            }
        );

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element,
            () =>
            {
                console.log('destroy');
              picker.destroy();
            }
        );
    },

    update: function(element, valueAccessor)
    {
        let value = valueAccessor();
        let unwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);

        const picker = $(element).data('pickrInstance');

        picker.setDate(unwrapped.toDate());
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't think knockout is to blame for this one. When I remove the custom binding from the test fiddle, I get similar results. Could the `destroy` method of the flatpickr library be broken? Using [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amjf0zs4/) and snapshotting in between pressing test, I can see the Objects count of `Flatpickr` increase per run...

Comment: Ah you're right, I was so focused on the ko binding... I made [a bug report](https://github.com/chmln/flatpickr/issues/796) and linked your Jsfiddle if you don't mind.

Comment: Can you post as an answer so I can mark it as the answer?